# Arc between two 3d vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, 3d, plot

How I can simply make an arc with a label in 3D Matlab plot? I have two 3D vectors (plot::Arrow3d)and I want to name an angle between them and I want to show it on 3D plot.

**Edit1:**
I use MuPad to render my drawing, I suppose to draw the arc between two vectors by plot::Arc3d(1, [0,0,0], n, al..bet). where n is simple to find. But I completely don't understand where the arc angle starts in 3D. Does somobody can show me how to find the zero angle.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, use the `text` function.

See if this gets you started:

```
%A couple of random points in 3 space
xyz1 = randn(3,1);
xyz2 = randn(3,1);

%Set up a figure, and create "arrow" plots within
figure(3781);
clf;
hold on
quiver3(0,0,0,xyz1(1), xyz1(2), xyz1(3),0,'b')
quiver3(0,0,0,xyz2(1), xyz2(2), xyz2(3),0,'r')
view(3)

%Add a line connecting teh arrows, and a text label
plot3([xyz1(1) xyz2(1)], [xyz1(2) xyz2(2)], [xyz1(3) xyz2(3)],'k:')
xyzCenter = mean([xyz1 xyz2],2);
h = text(xyzCenter(1), xyzCenter(2), xyzCenter(3), 'Label text here');
set(h,'Color','b')
get(h);  %For more properties to set
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work in MuPad. Mb you know how to do that here?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used MuPad and I can't spend too much time on stackoverflow research today.  Good luck.